# F#: IEnumerable<Tuple<TA,TB>> is not compatible with list<TA*TB>?

Tags: generics, f#, tuples

So I have the following code which is giving a **type mismatch** compiler error, and I don't know why:

```
[<Test>]
member this.TheTest() =
    let tuple = (DateTime.Now, 10)
    let listOfTuples = [ tuple ]
    SomeType.SomeFunc(listOfTuples)

static member SomeFunc (listOfTuples: IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime,int>>) =
    Console.WriteLine("foo")
```

Why are the types not compatible?

And more importantly, how can I express `SomeFunc`'s signature to be compatible with the call?

Comment: This is basically the same issue as: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21870026/65358  It's just a mismatch between System.Tuple and tuple expressions

Comment: It's not exactly the same, because the answers in that question talk about number of elements in a tuple, however in my question I'm just asking about a particular length of 2

Comment: @ReedCopsey: updated question, to express the ultimate purpose of it (which doesn't match the duplicate)

Comment: Have you tried `seq<DateTime * int>` instead of `IEnumerable<Tuple<DateTime,int>>`?

Comment: Note that replacing `IEnumerable` with `seq` is not necessary (they are truly equivalent), only convenient because it's shorter. The necessary part is replacing `Tuple<a,b>` with `a * b`.

Comment: @knocte That question is relevant.  The F# compiler won't treat tuple expressions and System.Tuple as equivalent, which is core issue here.  There are ways to work around this (using non-generic `IEnumerable`, use F# tuple syntax in the type specification, etc), but the underlying issue is the same here as there - `System.Tuple<'a,'b>` is not assignable from `('a * 'b)`...

Comment: yeah right, that is the explanation, but not the solution

Comment: @knocte Okay - Wrote out an answer with the full explanation + solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual issue here is trying to pass `('a * 'b)` into a function taking `Tuple<'a, 'b>`.  While the internal representation of these are the same, the F# compiler treats the two differently.

This is spelled out in the [F# language spec, section 6.3.2](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818827):

> When considered as static types, tuple types are distinct from their encoded form. However, the encoded form of tuple values and types is visible in the F# type system through runtime types.

The issue is that the compiler is using the "static types" to see if this function is a match, and according to the spec, it isn't.

> And more importantly, how can I express SomeFunc's signature to be compatible with the call?

You can work around this in various ways.  The simplest is to redefine the type specifications on your method to use tuple expressions as well:

```
static member SomeFunc (listOfTuples: IEnumerable<(DateTime * int)>) =
    Console.WriteLine("foo")
```

Note that the above can be written in a more idiomatic manner (with the exact same meaning) as:

```
static member SomeFunc (listOfTuples: (DateTime * int) seq) =
    Console.WriteLine("foo")
```